# Doctrine2 Duplicate key name error

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use doctrine2 migration and schema update with symfony2's console. All my entities are being generated with no problems via:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities myProject
```

Also, I am able to create my database and build my schema from scratch with no problems given the following commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Whenever I modify, remove, or add in another entity, I always regenerate my entities with:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities myProject
```

The problem however, is whenever I want to update my schema I always get the following error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE INDEX IDX_F7129A80A76ED395 ON  
   user_user (user_id)':                                                       

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name   
  'IDX_F7129A80A76ED395'                                                       






  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1061 Duplicate key name   
  'IDX_F7129A80A76ED395'
```

I have tried doing:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

or

```
php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

But I always get the same error. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way for me to update my database without having to destroy and build a whole new one every time? I have over 25 entities which consist of large files with many associative mappings (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany,.. etc) which seems to be causing problems. Any help would be great! Thanks!

On a side note I have a feeling that this piece of code might be causing the problem:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="myFriends")
 */
protected $friendsWithMe;

/**
 * @ORM\ ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="friendsWithMe")
 * @ORM\ JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\ JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\ JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $myFriends;
```

In my user entity, I wanted to build a self-referencing many to many relationship. This is how I'm building out a friends list. Maybe there is something wrong with my logic, but I took this directly off from the doctrine2 documentation on associative mapping.

Comment: check that you havent user_id duplicates in user table. If not you can try to delete all indexes manually and run `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: user_id does exist, but shouldn't doctrine know how to update the schema if it was the one that built it out? I hope doctrine won't force me to manually mess with the database because that's kind of a scary thought. It seems to me that doctrine is just ignoring my @JoinTable(name="friend" ... annotation. It is trying to build a table called user_user, with default settings even though I've clearly told it to use my settings.

Comment: mb spaces in annotations touch this? `@ORM\ JoinTable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it is the cause of the Exception, but there is an error in your ORM mapping. $myFriends is the owning side, $friendsWithMe is the inverse side, so `inversedBy` attribute should be only present on `$friendsWithMe`.

Try to rewrite `$myFriends`with `mappedBy` attribute :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="friendsWithMe")
 * @ORM\ JoinTable(name="friends",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\ JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\ JoinColumn(name="friend_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $myFriends;
```